# Magento - disable pagination ( not hide )

Tags: xml, magento-1.9, php

I'm using Magento 1.9, and I need to disable pagination for a specific category template. I'm already using a custom product_list.phtml and product_list_toolbar.phtml, but can't find anyway to disable the pagination. I just want to dump all products on the page. **I do not want to hide the toolbars**, I want to prevent the pagination functionality completely for a specific category.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is having this problem. I couldn't find an official way to stop pagination, so I found a work around. In the themes local.xml file I defined a new range(100) for the pagination, and set to the default. Then I hide the toolbars via the list.phtml file. This let me show all the product on a single page.

Example:
I was targeting category3

```
<CATEGORY_3>        
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>100</limit></action>
        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>100</limit></action>
        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>100</limit></action>          
    </reference>
</CATEGORY_3>
```